# Reordering Bar Graph with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, reorderlist

I need to reorder the bars in my bar chart from highest to lowest.  How do I do this?  Thank you in advance!

Here is my coding:

```
advertisement <- ("A", "B", "C")
times_shown <- c(900, 1000, 800)
clicks <- c(140, 180, 105)
leads <- c(55, 54, 40)

advertisement_all <- data.frame(advertisement, times_shown, clicks, leads)

message=FALSE}
advertisement_all %>%
  group_by(advertisement) %>%
  summarise(clicks / times_shown, leads / clicks, leads / times_shown) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = times_shown, y = leads, fill = advertisement)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Flanders' Roofing Advertisements", subtitle = 
         "Leads v. Times Shown", 
       caption = "Analysis by B. P. Newton") +
  xlab("Times Shown (#)") +
  ylab("Leads (#)") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Advertisement", labels = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

And here is my graph.  Variable "A" should be first, rather than in the middle, etc.

[image]

Comment: Aren't you naming the columns in `summarise`

Comment: Try `aes(x = reorder(times_shown,leads), y = leads, fill = advertisement)`